# How do i get the data stored in a list box by clicking on the particular row?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How do I get the data of a specific row stored in a list box by clicking on the particular row ? So if i click on the row i can then access that particular row by index then store it to be used later on

```
int myMaxResultValue = (int)nud_MaxResults.Value;
int myMaxSuggestValue = (int)nud_MaxSuggestions.Value;
findResults = objBvSoapClient( txt_Search.Text, txt_LastId.Text, cb_SearchFor.Text, text_Country.Text, text_LanguagePreference.Text, myMaxResultValue, myMaxSuggestValue);


if (txt_Search.Text.Length <= 2)// if less than two letters are entered nothing is displayed on the list.
{
    ls_Output.Items.Clear();// Clear LstBox
    ls_Output.Items.Add(String.Format(allDetails, "ID", "Text", "Highlight", "Cursor", "Description", "Next"));

    MessageBox.Show("Please enter more than 2 Chars!!");

}
else if (txt_Search.Text.Length >= 3)// if greater than or equal to 3 letters in the search box  continue search.
{
    // Get Results and store in given array.
    foreach (var items in findResults)
    {                
        //Loop through our collection of found results and change resulting value.
        ls_Output.Items.Add(String.Format(allDetails, items.Id, items.Text.ToString(), items.Highlight, items.Cursor, items.Description, items.Next));

    }


}
```

Then to retrieve the whole string i have placed this function within the indexChanged event,:

```
if (ls_Output.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    int itemAtPostion = ls_Output.SelectedIndex;
    string nextStep = "Retrieve";
    if (ls_Output.Items[itemAtPostion].ToString().Contains(nextStep))
    {
        string selItem = ls_Output.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected the following address: " + selItem);
        lst_Retreive.Text = ls_Output.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Comment: what is a `spefstored` ?

Comment: sorry spelling error now upadated, i did mean specific row

Comment: What we need from you is code showing us how you populated the listbox. What is this "data" you "stored" in it?

Comment: Updated my post and the data that is being stored is of type string an int. This is obtained from a web service

Comment: What i need to do is extract the Id from the string and use it at another point in the code and im strugllng to as i have the whole string stored in the var selItem but i cannot figuire out how to extract the id out of it as i will not know what it will be.

Comment: could you please post a set of possible entries from your `ListBox`?  This would be necessary to know to be able to answer your "how to extract the id out" question. It seems that you plunge all values into the listbox without any separator. Did I get it right?

Comment: what is the value of `allDetails` ?

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe There is a simple way to do this. Can you share the class in `findResults`, or at least the data types of its properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can either get the index of the item or the item itself.

To get the item you can use

```
string item = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

To get the index of the item you can use

```
int idx = listBox.SelectedIndex;
```

If your listbox supports multiselect you can use

```
var items = listBox.SelectedItems();
```

and

```
var idx = listBox.SelectedIndices;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this in a completly different way, and i should have been thinking about DataTables. I wanted to only be clicking on individual cells and hence the reason I was getting the whole string back rather than individual feilds. Heres how i Solved it

```
            DataTable ss = new DataTable();
            ss.Columns.Add("ID");
            ss.Columns.Add("Text");
            ss.Columns.Add("Highlight");
            ss.Columns.Add("Cursor");
            ss.Columns.Add("Description");
            ss.Columns.Add("Next");


            DataRow row = ss.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = findResults[0].Id;
            row["Text"] = findResults[0].Text;
            row["Highlight"] = findResults[0].Highlight;
            row["Cursor"] = findResults[0].Cursor;
            row["Description"] = findResults[0].Description;
            row["Next"] = findResults[0].Next;
            ss.Rows.Add(row);

            foreach (DataRow Drow in ss.Rows)
            {
                int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = Drow["id"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = Drow["Text"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = Drow["Highlight"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = Drow["Cursor"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[4].Value = Drow["Description"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[5].Value = Drow["Next"].ToString();


            }


            if (txt_Search.Text.Length <= 2)// if less than two letters are entered nothing is displayed on the list.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter more than 2 Chars!!");
            }

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            findResults.Clear();
```